# Laravel 5 passing page info with array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass data about the page state (navbar links having active class when you are in that exact page), page title. I do so with an indexed array $pageInfo, however I am getting a syntax error and doen't know where?

Also do you think this is a good method or should I use view->share() instead?

```
public function clases()
{
    $pageInfo[] = 
    (
        'page_title'      => 'Clases',
        'menu_active'     => 'CLases',
        'sub_menu_active' => '',
    );

    return view('clases.list', compact('pageInfo'));
}




public function domicilio()
{
    $pageInfo[] = 
    (
        'page_title'      => 'Clases a domicilio',
        'menu_active'     => 'Clases',
        'sub_menu_active' => 'Clases a domicilio',
    );

    return view('clases.domicilio', compact('pageInfo'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read [PHP basic syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php).

Basically you want to do this:

```
$pageInfo = 
[
    'page_title'      => 'Clases',
    'menu_active'     => 'CLases',
    'sub_menu_active' => '',
];
```

Arrays have a syntax of `[key => val, ...]` in PHP, you're using `()` as it seems.

Also `$someArray[] = someValue`, will append the `someValue` to an existing array, in your case that would create another, unwanted level of your array.

And last, you're not ending the `domicilio()` function. But I'll assume you just didn't paste it in (you should add `}` at the end, if that's not the case).